# Bash attempts to write two shell prompts?

Tags: bash, tty, strace

I am looking at the strace output of a running bash process connected to
a terminal, for educational purposes.

My bash process has PID 2883.

I type

```
[OP@localhost ~]$ strace -e trace=openat,read,write,fork,vfork,clone,execve -p 2883 2> bash.strace
```

Into a terminal. I then go into my bash process, and have the following
interaction:

```
[OP@localhost ~]$ ls
```

Looking at the output, I see

```
strace: Process 2883 attached
read(0, "l", 1)                         = 1
write(2, "l", 1)                        = 1
read(0, "s", 1)                         = 1
write(2, "s", 1)                        = 1
read(0, "\r", 1)                        = 1
write(2, "\n", 1)                       = 1
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fec6b1d8e50) = 3917
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=3917, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
write(1, "\33]0;OP@localhost:~\7", 23) = 23
write(2, "[OP@localhost ~]$ ", 22)  = 22
...
```

I am confused at the last two lines. It appears that bash is attempting
to write two shell prompts? What's going on here?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `<ESC>]0;` sequence (shown as `\33]0;` by strace) is the escape sequence to set the terminal window title. It's terminated with the BEL character (`\7`), so the first `write` sets the window title. The second prints the actual prompt. Note that even apart from the escape sequence, they're not exactly the same. The prompt has a surrounding `[..]` while the window title doesn't.

We can also see that the first write goes to stdout (fd 1, the first argument to `write()`), and the second to stderr. Bash prints the prompt to stderr, so the first write comes from somewhere else. That somewhere is probably `PROMPT_COMMAND`, like the one in Debian's default startup scripts for Bash. There's something like this in there:

```
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME}: ${PWD}\007"'
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

It sets that `PROMPT_COMMAND` if running `xterm` or `rxvt`, which should support that escape sequence.

Comment: Do you know why bash appears to read things character by character, rather than reading in a line at a time? Also, why does bash write "l" and "s" to stdout? If I do a similar strace with `cat`, there are two differences: it reads input line by line, and while it does echo its input back to stdout, I see the input twice (once when I type, and once when cat echoes it).

Comment: @extremeaxe5, that's basically because Bash (or rather the readline library) handles all the command line processing itself, instead of relying on the rather limited processing done by the terminal. It has to get the input immediately to decide what to do when e.g. a TAB character or `^A` (Ctrl-A) or the various special characters is pressed. Also, it turns the terminal's echo off, so that it can decide what to output for each particular input character (again, TAB doesn't usually output a TAB.) `cat` does none of that. If you it, try running `dash`, which doesn't do any command line handling.

Comment: Actually, the reason Bash calls `read()` to only read one byte at a time is that it can't read past a newline. The newline might cause it to run an external program, which might also read from the same input. (And that program should be able to read any characters after the newline.) If it didn't have to care about that, it could call `read()` with a larger limit, and with the terminal in raw mode, it would still _usually_ get the input one character at a time. (It would be up to how fast the input characters would arrive and how the process was scheduled.)

Comment: Your second comment appears to only be true because Bash does command-line handling itself.

Comment: @extremeaxe5, well, yes, I was assuming that, since it's the common case anyway. But, even if the shell relied on the terminal's line editing, the timing could still be an issue. If two lines were sent in quick succession (think pasting data), and the system was loaded enough so the shell wouldn't get immediately scheduled (or worse, the shell was stopped), then a `read()` with larger buffer might still return both lines in the same call. I don't think there's a guarantee that `read()` would _always_ return just one line in cooked mode.

Comment: If the input comes from a pipe, then there's no line handling outside the shell, but then again it's easy to tell if the input is connected to a terminal or not.